# Sending huge base64 image to PHP via POST

Tags: c#, php, image, post

I want to send a screenshot of my both screens to a PHP site via POST. It works fine, more or less.
Smaller images works fine, but bigger images causes problems.

I get this Visual Studio Error:
http://img.yuu.li/A34fPojk.png

I dont get any Error-Line and e.Result is empty too.
e.Error contains the message from the image.

This is my Code that may contains the error:

```
    private static void UploadFileCallback(Object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            FormHandler.manager.notify("Fehler!", "Folgender Fehler ist aufgetreten: \n" + e.Error, 4000);
            return;
        }

        busy = false;
        String result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Result);

        if (result.StartsWith("error"))
        {
            FormHandler.manager.notify("Fehler!", "Folgender Fehler ist aufgetreten: " + e.Result, 3000);
        }
        else
        {
            FormHandler.manager.notify("Fertig!", result, 3000);
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(result));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
```

My php.ini:
http://img.yuu.li/mqvm7fPb

Maybe someone of you can tell my what am i doing wrong? Everything is working great with smaller images. So i thought maybe the php.ini is blocking something.

My image in base64 is around 251096 characters long.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it myself, thanks anyway :D
Problem was, I have installed Froxlor with FCGID.
FCGID blocked the request because the max request length is 131072.
I added this

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 260000
```

in the file: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf